# Can I use super.someMethod to init a member variable in Java?

Tags: java, android, oop

it just simple Android code like this

there was a textview and a list view.

```
public class MaintActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView text = (TextView)super.findViewById(R.id.text);
    //cause android application crash
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          super.setContentView(R.layout.main);
          //when I write this.text = (TextView) super.findViewById(R.id.text); here, I get rid of crashing
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error?  BTW a compile error != a runtime exception != a crash.

Comment: it seems a runtime exception since I get rid of crashion when I comment this out and init the X inside a OnCreat member method.

Comment: There must be a stack trace which you can post for us? Without it, we cannot help you further.

Comment: I am sorry, now I put on the android code, please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, there's nothing wrong in calling a method when initializing a variable in Java. However, in this specific case:

```
private TextView text = (TextView)super.findViewById(R.id.text);
```

You cannot call `findViewById()` before `onCreate()`. The code will NPE because the activity `Window` has not yet been set up. Also you likely want to call it after `setContentView()` so it will actually have a chance of returning something.

In Android activities in general, you shouldn't really be doing anything at runtime before `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong in general with calling superclass methods and getting return values from them.  There might be a problem with the particular method you're calling, or the way you're calling it, or what you're doing with the result, but merely calling a superclass method and assigning its result to a variable is not an error.

Comment: my bad, now I put on the code please help me :)

Answer (score 0):

As [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24753111/2821954) by laalto, the real issue is not the use of `super` keyword, but `NullPointerException` due to `Activity` cannot find the view before it is set-up in `onCreate()`.

As for your question title itself: *yes, you can*, and you've tested it by yourself.

This will run without error if you "fix" your code to: (using the same code as yours)

```
public class MaintActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView text;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          super.setContentView(R.layout.main);
          this.text = (TextView) super.findViewById(R.id.text);
    }
}
```

Though, it's strange in this case, since `setContentView()` and `findViewById()` will certainly not be overridden. Better to use `this` or no keyword at all.

Comment: thanks for your answer, what do you mean better to use this or no keyword at all?

Comment: You don't really need to use `super` for most of the functions. You can just type `setContentView(R.layout.main);` and `this.text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);`.